# background-image style of node not working with SVG images

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

When I set node background-image to a SVG file zoom in/out changes background image. This makes ugly visuals. PNG does not have that problem.

This is a node with SVG background [image: image initially fine]

This is the same node when I zoom in. You can see image is also zoomed in
[image: image when I zoomed in]

Comment: I'm pretty sure adding preserveAspectRatio to your svg code will help (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio).  I haven't verified though.

Comment: I will try that thanks

Comment: The problem was inside the SVG file. For some SVGs, I observed this problem. I remember if I set the width and height of SVG I wouldn't observe this problem. `preserveAspectRatio` inside SVG might also help

Comment: defining `viewBox` or `width` and `height` helped me

Comment: `width` and `height` seems like necessary for not flickering image in some cases

Answer (score 5):

This is a runnable code to demonstrate the use of `background-image` with SVG graphic. The SVG code must be appropriately encoded before use. Try to run the code below then zoom in and out (press control key and use scroll wheel on the mouse). The SVG graphic will scale correctly with the node.

```js
const svg_pin =
  '<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M12,11.5A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 9.5,9A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 12,6.5A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 14.5,9A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 12,11.5M12,2A7,7 0 0,0 5,9C5,14.25 12,22 12,22C12,22 19,14.25 19,9A7,7 0 0,0 12,2Z" fill="yellow"></path></svg>';

const svgpin_Url = encodeURI("data:image/svg+xml;utf-8," + svg_pin);


var cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById("cy"),

  elements: {
    nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: "j",
          name: "John"
        },
        position: {
          x: 100,
          y: 100
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "e",
          name: "Elena"
        },
        position: {
          x: 100,
          y: 500
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "k",
          name: "Kim"
        },
        position: {
          x: 600,
          y: 500
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "g",
          name: "Gordon"
        },
        position: {
          x: 550,
          y: 80
        }
      }
    ],

    edges: [{
        data: {
          source: "j",
          target: "e",
          label: "JE"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "j",
          target: "g",
          label: "JG"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "e",
          target: "j"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "k",
          target: "j"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "k",
          target: "e",
          label: "KE"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "k",
          target: "g"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "g",
          target: "j"
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  style: [{
      selector: "node",
      style: {
        shape: "hexagon",
        "background-color": "blue",
        "background-image": svgpin_Url,
        label: "data(name)",
        opacity: 0.55
      }
    },
    {
      selector: "edge",
      style: {
        label: "data(label)",
        width: 3,
        "line-color": "#c0c",
        "target-arrow-color": "#00c",
        "curve-style": "bezier",
        "target-arrow-shape": "triangle",
        "target-arrow-fill": "#c00",
        "arrow-scale": 20
      }
    },
    {
      selector: ".highlight",
      css: {
        "background-color": "yellow"
      }
    }
  ],
  layout: {
    name: "preset"
  }
});
```

```css
#cy {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/2.7.10/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
<div id="cy"></div>
```

Comment: the key things are inside the SVG. `width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"`

Comment: @canbax Not just that, but also `<path d="..." />` that declares the marker's geometry shape within the viewbox.

Answer (score 0):

Some SVGs aren't always handled properly by the browser.  Make your SVG as robust as possible and test as much as possible. There are hints in the documentation to make your SVG as compatible as possible: https://js.cytoscape.org/#style/background-image

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
.element {
  background-image: url(/images/image.svg);
}
```

Comment: An explanation (even very short) of why your code-only answer actually addresses and solves the problem improves your answer a lot !